# Android Studio Electric Eel Preview missing option to enable Live Edit

Tags: android, android-studio, liveedit

`Android Studio Electric Eel Preview` version allows for `Live Edits` but I don't see an option to turn it on in the settings. I only see an option to turn on `Live Edit of Literals` in the Live Edit options dialog. I downloaded Eel from [this Google page](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html). How can I enable Live Edit?

**This should be displayed**

[image]

**But It's missing from my copy of Eel**

[image]

Comment: Its a preview release so you cant expect everything to be right. Atleast not to be similar

Comment: I also have this problem too! any updates ?

Comment: If you're not using gradle version alpha. Please don't use material alpha version.

Comment: User this version instead : implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'

Comment: New studio version, need all new gradle and other lib versions.